# Optimise custom function with multiple args to accept ranges

Tags: google-apps-script, google-sheets, custom-function

The developers guide of google apps suggests to write your function to accept ranges for optimization like this:

```
function DOUBLE(input) {
  if (input.map) {            // Test whether input is an array.
    return input.map(DOUBLE); // Recurse over array if so.
  } else {
    return input * 2;
  }
}
```

I wonder how you would that with multiple arguments?
e.g

```
function DOUBLEandADD(doubleThis, addThis){
    return (doubleThis * 2) + addThis;
}
```

Do you check both at once and how do you iterate over the ranges?

Something like this perhaps?

```
function DOUBLEandADD(doubleThis, addThis) {
   if (doubleThis.map && addThis.map){
       var d = Array.from(doubleThis.values());
       var a = Array.from(addThis.values());

       for (var i = 0; i < d.length(); i++){
            return DOUBLEandADD(d[i],a[i]);
       }
   } else {
       return (doubleThis * 2) + addThis;
   }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You would wrap the the map function in an anonymous function and pass the additional parameters.

```
function DOUBLEandADD(input,addend) {
  if (input.map) {           
    return input.map(function(i){return DOUBLEandADD(i,addend)}); 
  } else {
    return (input * 2) + addend;
  }
}
```

Comment: addend is constant here, if I understand correctly, but I want both args to possibly be ranges.

Comment: Using 2 ranges will be extremely custom to the specific need of function. A single working solution will not cover all cases. As of now the question is too broad to answer. Focus your question.

Answer (score 1):

I wouldn't use `map` in your case. How about this:

```
function DOUBLEandADD(doubleThis, addThis) {
  if (Array.isArray(doubleThis) || Array.isArray(addThis)) {
    if (!Array.isArray(doubleThis) ||
        !Array.isArray(addThis) ||
        doubleThis.length != addThis.length) {
      throw new Error("doubleThis and addThis arrays must be same length.");
    }
    var results = [];
    for (var i = 0; i < doubleThis.length; i++) {
      results.push((doubleThis[i] * 2) + addThis[i]);
    }
    return results;
  } else {
    return (doubleThis * 2) + addThis;
  }
}
```